# How to add unique query in updateAll psql

Tags: postgresql, orm, nestjs

```
let query=`created BETWEEN NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INTEGER-7  AND NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW from NOW())::INTEGER`;

let result = await this.sampleRequestsRepository.updateAll(
      {

        `${query}`
      },
      { "deleatedAt": true },
    );

    console.log(result );
```

I am trying to run this, but it does not allow me to add a query like this. I want to run unique query inside `updateAll`.

Answer (score -1):

we can use **js** and **Between** ,

```
 let today = new Date();
let weekAgo = new Date();
weekAgo.setDate(weekAgo.getDate() - 7);
```

`let result = await this.sampleRequestsRepository.updateAll(`
`{

```
    updatedAt: Between(weekAgo, today)
  },
  { "deleatedAt": true },
);`,
```

Comment: What is `Between`?